# How to set constraint with a specific width and height view

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I had set some constraints with visual format language to my UIImageView( a little star).

Here is my code:

```
        //Bottom
    format = @"V:|-[_title]-|";
    constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [_bottom addConstraints:constraintsArray];

    format = @"V:|-[_stars(==17)]-|";
    constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [_bottom addConstraints:constraintsArray];

    format = @"V:|-15-[_number]-15-|";
    constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [_bottom addConstraints:constraintsArray];

    format = @"H:|-[_title(240)]-[_stars(17)]-[_number]-|";
    constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [_bottom addConstraints:constraintsArray];
```

Note that the _bottom is the super view where I added constraints and I had set the `_stars's frame` to `17 * 17`. But the position of the `_stars` is not at the vertical center.

[image]

How can I fix this? This is what i want. **Is there a way to set the view to vertival center?**

[image]

Thanks a lot for advice.

**Edit：** _bottom 's code.

```
    format = @"V:|[_top(100)][_bottom]|";
    constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [_background addConstraints:constraintsArray];

    format = @"H:|[_bottom]|";
    constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [_background addConstraints:constraintsArray];
```

Comment: What is the resolution of the star image and what is content mode of imageView?

Comment: @gabbler It is a 64 X 64 png image. The contentMode default is `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`. I did't change it.

Comment: Try to add this:`[self.bottom removeConstraints:self.bottom.constraints];
`

Comment: are you sure that the frame of image view is 17 * 17? because in the image you posted under my answer the frame of image view does not look like 17 * 17. It looks like image view's height equals to super view's height.

Comment: @wcd No, I mean I set to 17*17. Original is 64 * 64.

Comment: ah, I've found what's wrong with your constraints. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: have you tried `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY` as your options for the constraints describing the y-axis for the star?

Comment: @LouisTur Yes I tried, but not work.

Comment: huh? not working? but you accepted my answer. Does it work or not? I'm confused, man. Let me help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
[_bottom addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint 
                            constraintWithItem:_stars
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY 
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                        toItem:_bottom
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY 
                                    multiplier:1.0f 
                                      constant:0.0f]];


//Bottom
format = @"V:|-[_title]-|";
constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
[_bottom addConstraints:constraintsArray];

format = @"V:[_stars(17)]"; // @"V:|-[_stars(==17)]-|" -> @"V:[_stars(17)]"
constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
[_bottom addConstraints:constraintsArray];

format = @"V:|-15-[_number]-15-|";
constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
[_bottom addConstraints:constraintsArray];

format = @"H:|-[_title(240)]-[_stars(17)]-[_number]-|";
constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
[_bottom addConstraints:constraintsArray];
```

Not all constraints can be created with visual format string.

Comment: Thanks @wcd, I tried your answer, but unfortunately, it now looks like this.http://i.imgur.com/u8R66XH.png. The star image became strange.

Comment: @WorldOfWarcraft what is the frame of `_bottom`? `_stars`'s frame in this picture is not 17 * 17. The height of `_stars` equals to the height of super view. Check frame and content mode of `_stars`.

Comment: `_bottom` is a UIView with its backgroundColor. And the `_stars`' resolution is  72 pixels/inch. I posted my `_bottom` and edited.

Comment: Cheers! Thanks very much. Work perfect!